# New page with onclick on a div but not the children div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want that a click on div 'Bandeau-1' or 'Bandeau-2'... open a new page.
I have 4 selector who change 'Bandeau-1' to 'Bandeau-2'.
But if you click on the selector, you open a new page (because they are in the div).

How i can say : onclick on the div 'Bandeau-1' or 'Bandeau-2'... open a new page and onclick on a selectore change 'Bandeau' and don't open a new page ?

```
<? 
echo "<div class='Bandeau-Actu' name='Bandeau-1' style='background: url(Include/img/Bandeau/$Bandeau_Image1);' onClick=\"window.location.href='$Bandeau_Web1'\">"; 
?>
      <div id='Bandeau_Cadre_Bouton'>
      <div class='Bandeau-Bouton' onclick="Click_Selector_Bandeau(1);">1</div>
      <div class='Bandeau-Bouton' onclick="Click_Selector_Bandeau(2);">2</div>
      <div class='Bandeau-Bouton' onclick="Click_Selector_Bandeau(3);">3</div>
      <div class='Bandeau-Bouton' onclick="Click_Selector_Bandeau(4);">4</div>
      </div>

</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: just use `onclick="event.stopPropagation();"` in child `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`event.stopPropagation();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation)

```
<div class='Bandeau-Bouton' onclick="event.stopPropagation(); Click_Selector_Bandeau(1);">1</div>
<div class='Bandeau-Bouton' onclick="event.stopPropagation(); Click_Selector_Bandeau(2);">2</div>
<div class='Bandeau-Bouton' onclick="event.stopPropagation(); Click_Selector_Bandeau(3);">3</div>
<div class='Bandeau-Bouton' onclick="event.stopPropagation(); Click_Selector_Bandeau(4);">4</div>
```

It stops the click event from bubbling up to parent elements.